# Compiling C++ program that has an error with not finding the file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am new to using the Visual Studio Code. I found this through a friend and he suggested that this is the programming app that you should use for using my Macbook pro. I am trying to write codes in C++ for a college class. When I type in the code into the Visual studio code app, I will try to compile the code by clicking on the Terminal tab and then type in g++ then the title of the file. I save the file in two different places. When I hit enter and an clang error comes up with "no such file or directory:" then the file name. Then right below it is a clang error saying "no input files:" How would I get that to compile?

Comment: You have to give the correct path to the file, which depends on where you save it and where you currently are. Easiest fix is just giving the absolute path, which should be something like `/Users/Emily/Desktop/myfile.cpp` or something. Otherwise, you have to navigate to the folder (in the terminal) and then type `clang++ mtfile.cpp`

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason for this, I would not store the source in two different locations. Store it in one location. When you open the VS Code terminal, the current working directory will depend on where you started VS Code from. You can simply `cd folder1/folder2` as needed to get to where your source code is to run g++. Or find a VS Code extension that will do C++ compilation for you, hence no need for terminal access.

Comment: "_by clicking on the Terminal tab and then type_"... If you instead type `pwd`, what directory does it show? If it shows a path in your home directory, type `find . -type f` to list all the files in that directory (and sub directories). If the list is not too long, you can copy that into your question (into a code block). Indicate which file you want to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sour you navigate to the same folder with the terminal, where you saved the file. For example:

```
C:\myCodes>
```

you can navigate via linuc comands like cd <folderName>:

```
C:> cd .\myCodes
C:\myCodes>
```

then you should be able to compile by:

```
C:\myCodes> g++ myFile.cpp
```

or you can use:

```
C:\myCodes> g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic myFile.cpp
```

for more clever warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find the correct folder is to right click the file and [choose Open in Integrated Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaRvq.png). Then you just type `g++ myFile.cpp` and it should build as expected.